# Solving 3 x 3 by Elimination Method

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{cases}
7c_1-10c_2-c_3&=0\\
-14c_1+15c_2&=0\\
6c_1+\dfrac{15}{14}c_2+3c_2&=0
\end{cases}

In the link above is the image for the 3 equations. After elimination, I ended up getting 0=0 meaning infinite solutions, like the text states. But how did they get a specific solution which works for all 3 equations?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Find the null space of
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 7 & -10 & -1 \\
 -14 & 15 & 0 \\
 6 & \frac{15}{14} & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**Augmented reduction of** $\mathbf{A}^{*}$

*Column 1*

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{10}{7} & 1 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrc|ccc}
 7 & -14 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -10 & 15 & \frac{15}{14} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 \boxed{1} & -2 & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -5 & \frac{135}{14} & \frac{10}{7} & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & \frac{27}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

*Column 2*

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -\frac{2}{5} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 \boxed{1} & -2 & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -5 & \frac{135}{14} & \frac{10}{7} & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & \frac{27}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -3 & -\frac{3}{7} & -\frac{2}{5} & 0 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & -\frac{27}{14} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{1}{5} &
   0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-\frac{3}{7}} & \color{red}{-\frac{2}{5}} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

---

$$
 \mathbf{A}
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\color{red}{-\frac{3}{7}} \\ \color{red}{-\frac{2}{5}} \\ \color{red}{1} 
\end{array} \right) =
\left( \begin{array}{r}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{array} \right)
$$